# How to do value search in rejson data type?

Tags: redis

I have few documents stored in redis using rejson

```
data1:{"a":"abs","b":{"c":123}}
data2:{"a":"sss","b":{"c":633}}
data3:{"a":"abs","b":{"c":633}}
```

I would like to extract all the data that has "a"=="abs" using json.get in python but everywhere it's told it is not possible to do element search but is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

For RedisJSON >=2.0 you can use RediSearch >=2.2 to create secondary indices on specific fields in RedisJSON documents, that afterwards can be queried.

https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/indexing_JSON/